# Variable accessibility with require_once/ob_start()

Tags: php, apache, ob-start

Maybe I'm just tired or just am simply confused, but I'm having a strange issue dealing with some `require_once()` calls and `ob_start()`.

**Basic Structure:**

**Top of Main.php:**

```
require_once 'config.php'; // includes variable $A = "bar", and Function "foo"

function getPage(){
  ob_start();
  include 'some_file.php';
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  echo $html;
  die();
}
getPage();
```

**some_file.php**

```
require_once 'config.php'; // includes same config file
var_dump($A); // NULL
foo(); // runs, returns correct value
```

**Config.php**

```
$A = 'bar';

function foo(){
  return "FOO";
}
```

So, what is wrong here? I'm including a file while buffering output. The required file `config.php` holds a variable and function. When including `some_file.php` during the buffer, the variable `$A` is apparently NOT set/accessible. The function `foo` CAN execute.

Comment: Are there functions involved (in either main.php or some_file.php) that you're not showing us?

Comment: Where are you using `$A` that is apparently not set? Show us a more complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please.

Comment: Whenever you do include/require, classes and functions are declared within the global scope; variables in the file being included is only available right after the include statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) says:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your provided code does not illustrate the problem that you're describing. When I run it as-is, it correctly shows that the variable is defined.

---

That being said, the thing to remember is that what looks like a global variable in an included file actually ends up in the scope of the function that's calling it. So if the first time `require_once()` is called is from a function, the `$A` variable is scoped to the function - and disappears when the function returns, just like any other variable defined inside the function.

If you absolutely must define a global variable inside an included file (are you sure? really?), make sure you only include that file from the global scope - not from within a function. If you need to access the variable from within a function, include the file outside the function, and then use the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword to access the variable from within the function.